# AdaGrad: motivation and complex values

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, gradient-descent, adagrad

I have started learning the math behind the AdaGrad optimizer, and two questions emerged that I cannot find any answers on the Internet:

1. It is said that in AdaGrad *"parameters associated with low-frequency features tend to have larger learning rates than parameters associated with high-frequency features"*. But how can we tell feature frequency from the weight gradients? Also, same weight can be associated with different features, so isn't it a problem for this "feature-frequency"-interpretation? Yes, it looks like AdaGrad slows down weights that are updated rapidly, but how does it relate to feature frequency?
2. When the AdaGrad's weight-update rule is the "diagonal-only" version $${\displaystyle x_{t+1}=x_{t}-\eta {\text{diag}}(G_{t})^{-1/2}\odot g_{t}},$$ there is no problem in taking a square root of elements on the diagonal, as they are 100% non-negative values (because they're squared gradients). But when the update rule is the "full-historical-gradient-matrix" version $${\displaystyle x_{t+1}=x_{t}-\eta (G_{t})^{-1/2}g_{t}},$$ then we must compute the square roots of non-diagonal elements that can be negative. Isn't it a problem? Looks like, it will lead to complex weights.

Comment: Where are you getting these from? It's hard to know what you're talking about without any sources to see the context.